# how to make a custom ionic tabs?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have been developing application in ionic 2 using ionic 2 tabs template. 
I want to make a big plus button in the middle . I am attaching screenshot if anyone can tell me how to achieve that .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Nlz.jpg)

Comment: I posted a working example to get it, i used css because I don't know ionic framwork may be it will help you.

Comment: yes i know it can be done with css but i want to use it in ionic tabs template which i am unable to do so

Comment: Okay but can use the same logic to get it.

Comment: actually ionic tabs are not allowing too many customization. Thats the probelm

Comment: As far as I know this is not a feature that ionic supports. You have to write your own css do do that.